# Marginal density function involving exponential and uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

for my probability homework I was given the following question.

Let $Y \sim$ Exponential(2) and let $X \sim$ Uniform$(0, e^{Y})$. This means that $(X, Y)$ is a bivariate continuous random variabele with joint density function $f_{X, Y}: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by:

\begin{align*}
f_{X, Y}(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
2e^{-3y}, & 0 < x < e^{y}, y > 0; \\
0, & \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

For the third question I had to determine the marginal density function $f_{X}(x)$. I know that I have to integrate the above function over the support of $Y$, however, they gave the hint that I have to distinguish two different cases, which makes me unsure about what to do. Originally I would just integrate from 0 to $\infty$, but now I am not sure. I tried to make a plot of the bounds and thought I would have to approach two different cases involving $x$ between 0 and 1, and $x$ > 1, but I am not sure how I would approach this in the integral. I would greatly appreciate if anybody could help!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you see that the conditional pdf $f_{X|Y=y}(x) = \frac{1}{e^{y}}\,\,,0\leq x\leq e^{y} $

Then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X|Y=y}(x)f_{Y}(y)=\frac{2e^{-2y}}{e^{-y}}\,\,\,,0\leq x\leq e^{y}=2e^{-3y}\,\,,0\leq x\leq e^{y}\,,y>0$

Now to find the Marginal pdf of $X$ , you have to integrate over $y$.

But notice that when $x\geq 1$ then  $x\leq e^{y}\iff\ln(x)\leq y$

Thus $\displaystyle f_{X}(x)=\int_{\ln(x)}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy=\int_{\ln(x)}^{\infty}2e^{-3y}\,dy =\frac{2}{3x^{3}}\,\,,1\leq x<\infty$

And when $0\leq x \leq 1$ Then  for all $y\geq 0$ , $x\leq e^{y}$

So $f_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}2e^{-3y}\,dy=\frac{2}{3}$

Thus $\displaystyle f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{3x^{3}}\,\,,x\geq 1\\\\\frac{2}{3}\,\,,0\leq x<1\end{cases}$

Check that the integral over $x$ of $f_{X}(x)$ is $1$.